# Disable warmers on replicas in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on a cluster that handles a lot of complex aggregation calculations. This means that our field data cache gets large. Furthermore data is bulk loaded at certain times of the day.

Ideally we only want the primary shards to serve requests and let the replica act as a failover. We can do this via the preferences API but it introduces one of two issues...

If we just set the fields to be lazy loaded then right after a bulk load, things take a bit to cache. This causes a huge spike in response times. If we enable eager loading then field data eats up a lot of memory on the replicas. Same goes for using warmers (unless there is a way to disable them for replicas).

What I want is eager on the primaries and lazy on the replicas. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible in Elasticsearch (sorry!)